# Spring Boot 3 Upgrade - Spring Data JPA Deadlocks on insert to MariaDb at Concurrency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm upgrading from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3.1.
Generally the application runs fine, however our API tests frequently fail since the upgrade due to a high amount of JPA Deadlock Exceptions. Such Deadlocks did not at all occur with Version 2 - it's the first time I am seeing them, and now they happen very often (~40% of tests will fail due to these deadlock exceptions).

What I can see is that it's all inserts and it's all going to the same table, which isn't very big and does not have a lot of indexes to it (one foreign key index and one index on a state; that's it). There's not a single such exception on a different table, while some of them getting way more writes than this one.

Has anyone seen such a behaviuor before?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute batch [(conn=1247) Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction] [insert into `order_purchase_order` (`buyer_purchase_order_comment`,`created_at`,`current_state`,`last_modified_at`,`order_id`,`state_history`,`supplier_dialect_id`,`supplier_id`,`supplier_id_name`,`supplier_name`,`supplier_sales_order_reference`,`id`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect.lambda$buildSQLExceptionConversionDelegate$3(MySQLDialect.java:1178)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchImpl.lambda$performExecution$2(BatchImpl.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.PreparedStatementGroupSingleTable.forEachStatement(PreparedStatementGroupSingleTable.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchImpl.performExecution(BatchImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchImpl.execute(BatchImpl.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.getBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorSingleBatched.resolveBatch(MutationExecutorSingleBatched.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorSingleBatched.performBatchedOperations(MutationExecutorSingleBatched.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.execute(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2670)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:489)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:486)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1412)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2296)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1961)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:561)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: (conn=1247) Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createBatchUpdate(ExceptionFactory.java:215)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.executePipeline(StandardClient.java:637)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchPipeline(ClientPreparedStatement.java:196)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternalPreparedBatch(ClientPreparedStatement.java:128)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ClientPreparedStatement.java:466)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:127)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchImpl.lambda$performExecution$2(BatchImpl.java:275)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: (conn=1247) Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:296)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:370)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.message.ClientMessage.readPacket(ClientMessage.java:134)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readPacket(StandardClient.java:872)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResults(StandardClient.java:811)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResponse(StandardClient.java:730)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.executePipeline(StandardClient.java:571)
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```